# RoR 4.2.0 Jquery not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my ror application i've a jquery error during the execution. On the Google Chrome Application appear this message

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

this is my application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .


$(function(){ 
    $(document).foundation('alert'); 
});
```

In the gemfile is present the jquery-rails gem.

I really don't know where crush my head. All the help is appreciated

Comment: Have you loaded `jQuery` before using it?

Comment: Is this in production and have you precompiled assets?

Comment: @Tushar but Rails  doesn't load it automatically when you install the gem and your manifest have '= require jquery' ?

Answer (score -1):

remove Gemfile.lock
do

```
$bundle install
```

now check if jQuery works